# Update the values of idx column if character matches in the vals columns for the given data

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, optimization, python-itertools

I want to update the numbers in `idx` field if there is any matching letter between the `vals` from two consecutive row.

```
Input data = '''pos\tidx\tvals
    23\t4\tabc
    25\t7\tatg
    29\t8\tctb
    35\t1\txyz
    37\t2\tmno
    39\t3\tpqr
    41\t6\trtu
    45\t5\tlfg'''

‘’’ Explantion: Since there is letter `a` matching between idx 4 and 7
the idx at pos 25 will be updated to 4, but again there is `t`
matching between vals at pos 25 and 29 we update the idx at 29 also to   
4 instead of just 7. ‘’’

#Expected output to a file (tab separated):
pos    idx    vals
23    4    abc
25    4    atg
29    4    ctb
35    1    xyz
37    2    mno
39    3    pqr
41    3    rtu
45    5    lfg
```

I have written the given code so far, and would also like to

- write the expected output to a file
- optimize the code for the work I am doing.
- the answer has to follow my method of reading two consecutive rows (as keys, values) pairs at a time. The reason is this question is just a trial of other problem I am trying to solve.

**Code:**

```
import csv
import itertools
import collections
import io
from itertools import islice

data_As_Dict = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(data), delimiter='\t')
grouped = itertools.groupby(data_As_Dict, key=lambda x: x['idx'])

write_to = open(“updated_idx.txt”, “w”)
write_to.write(‘\t’.join([‘pos’, ‘idx’, ‘vals’]))
write_to.close()

# Make a function to read the data as keys,values and also keep the order
def accumulate(data):
    acc = collections.OrderedDict()
    for d in data:
        for k, v in d.items():
            acc.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
    return acc


''' Store data as keys,values '''
grouped_data = collections.OrderedDict()
for k, g in grouped:
    grouped_data[k] = accumulate(g)


# Now, read as keys, values pairs for two consecutive keys
for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in zip(grouped_data.items(), islice(grouped_data.items(), 1, None)):

    pos1 = v1[‘pos’]
    pos2 = v2[‘pos’]    

    v1_vals = ''.join(v1['vals'])
    v2_vals = ''.join(v2['vals'])

    v1_vals = list(v1_vals)
    v2_vals = list(v2_vals)

    # find if there are any matching letters between two vals
    commons = [x for x in v1_vals if x in v2_vals]

    # start updating the idx values if there is a match
    if len(commons) > 0:
        k2_new = k1 

    write_to = open(“updated_idx.txt”, “a”)
    write_to.write(‘\t’.join([pos1, k1 , v1[‘vals’]))
    write_to.write(‘\t’.join([pos2, k2_new , v2[‘vals’]))

    # Problem: This (above) method updates the k2 for one consecutive match ..
      # but, I want to keep this value (k1) and update it if..
      # .. elements keep matching.

      # this may also be improved using lambda
      # any other alternatives ??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not misunderstanding and you just care for consecutive rows you probably can just do it with something like this:

```
data = '''pos\tidx\tvals
    23\t4\tabc
    25\t7\tatg
    29\t8\tctb
    35\t1\txyz
    37\t2\tmno
    39\t3\tpqr
    41\t6\trtu
    45\t5\tlfg'''

def is_one_char_in_string(stringa, stringb):
    for char in stringa:
        if char in stringb:
            return True
    return False
prev_idx=''
prev_val=''
with open("out.txt", "a") as of:
    for i, line in enumerate(data.split("\n")):
        line=line.strip().split("\t")
        # Header and first row doesn't need to be considered for reindexing
        if i<2:
            prev_idx=line[1]
            prev_val=line[2]
            of.write("\t".join(line)+"\n")
        else:
            if is_one_char_in_string(line[2], prev_val):
                line[1]= prev_idx
                of.write("\t".join(line)+"\n")
                prev_val=line[2]
            else:
                prev_idx=line[1]
                prev_val=line[2]
                of.write("\t".join(line)+"\n")
```

**edit to follow the same method as the original question - updated**

Turned out that when I copied the input data I left the tabulation at the start of the line, which made the csv reader consider it as a column, messing up the keys. So this should be correct.

```
f = open ("out.txt", "a")
f.write("pos\tidx\tvals\n")
for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in zip(grouped_data.items(), islice(grouped_data.items(), 1, None)):
    # find if there are any matching letters between two vals
    commons = [x for x in v1['vals'][0] if x in v2['vals'][0]]
    # start updating the idx values if there is a match
    if len(commons) > 0:
        # Update the dictionary with the new key
        grouped_data[k2]['idx'] = grouped_data[k1]['idx']

    f.write("{}\t{}\t{}\n".format(v1['pos'][0], v1['idx'][0], v1['vals'][0]))
# write the last row, previously updated
last_row = list(grouped_data.items())[-1][1]
f.write("{}\t{}\t{}\n".format(last_row['pos'][0], last_row['idx'][0], last_row['vals'][0]))
f.close()
```

**answer to OP comment**

I corrected the code above. Else is not needed because you want to update (or "carry on") the index only if the next string matches. You can add `else: pass` if it makes the code more readable for you.

**Optimization**
For the optimization, using sets, as suggested by Raymond Zheng, could speed up things a bit in case of long strings.
To check for common elements using sets:

```
commons = list(set(v1['vals'][0]).intersection(set(v2['vals'][0])))
```

But depending on the length of your strings it could degrade performance (albeit both of them are quite fast).
Just for the record for 100 iterations timed with timeit:

```
-on strings of length 4
lists: 0.00011 sec.
sets:  0.00022 sec.
-on strings of length 200
lists: 0.00222 sec.
sets:  0.00123 sec.
-on strings of length 2000
lists: 0.02354 sec.
sets:  0.00930 sec.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it has to follow my method of reading two consecutive rows (as keys, values) pairs at a time. The reason is this question is just a trial of other problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Edited to loosely follow your method. I don't know what else are you trying to achieve, so I don't know if it breaks something.

Comment: I am not understanding why are you updating `vals` in `grouped_data[k2]['vals'] = grouped_data[k1]['vals']` instead of `idx`. Also, there is no `else`. I don’t have problem writing `if else and for loop` but the main issue is carrying that `idx` values along several `for - loops of k1,v1; k2,v2` when the consecutive keeps matching. Can you also please upvote the question to gather some attention? Thank you so much for looking into the problem.

Comment: I updated the answer, check if it solves your problem.

Comment: Hi Hira: All is good, but with your former code the update fails when data is a little different like `data = '''pos\tidx\tvals
21\t9\tdbf
23\t4\tabc
25\t7\tatg
29\t8\tctb
35\t1\txyz
37\t2\tmno
39\t3\tpqr
41\t6\trtu
45\t5\tlfg'''`. With you later code it fails to write the last line. I had to do some thinking over `for loop` and found the following solution: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186829/update-the-idx-values-if-vals-element-match-between-consecutive-rows , but it may not be optimal. I can remove that `for range ... ` part if I am using `with open(...)`.

Comment: Sorry for that. You can add the last row simply taking the last element of your ordereddict, that has been updated during the loop. I updated the answer with this last bit. I also fixed the simple iterative first method, I forgot to update the variable prev_value with the new value.

Answer (score 1):

**Writing file:**

```
f = open(filename, 'w')
f.write("Beginning code execution)

for (k1, v1), (k2, v2)... 
    # your code here
    ...
    f.write(...)
f.write("End code execution")
```

---

**Optimizations:**

Some optimizations can come from the actual logic of the problem. Just looking at your code though, change `v2_vals = list(v2_vals)` to `v2_vals = set(v2_vals)`. Prevents iterations over long strings, and also has a max size of 26 (or whatever the valid character set is for values).

---

**The problem you specified in your comment:**

Unfortunately there's no easy way to "redo" a loop iteration. You can, however, iterate manually:

```
i = 0
while i < len(...):
    ...
    if len(commons) > 0:
        k2_new = k1
        continue # <-- skips the i += 1. You can additionally save the k1 value so as to not have to recalculate.
    i += 1
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you please add more details, or full workable code.